# How to change Layout params in Activity from Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have these layouts in my activity:

- LinearLayout1
- LinearLayout2
- Frame1
- Frame2 (View.Gone)

And I have FragmentA in Frame1. How can I make

```
Frame1.setVisibility(View.Gone);
Frame2.setVisibility(View.Visible);
fragment = Fragmnt2();
fragmentTransaction.replace(Frame2, fragment);
```

from the Fragment? How can I get access to parent Activity from fragment?

Answer (score 1):

you can use getActivity() to get the parent activity but make sure onCreate has been called first otherwise getActivity() could be null.

Comment: How can i change layout params of activity.xml from fragment? Post please a peace of code

Comment: @KostyaKhuta call View.getLayoutParams() to get layout parans

Comment: You can create new LayoutParams(); and add this to whatever view you need to chante.  something like this:

 TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams trparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            tr.setLayoutParams(trparams);